# Grafana PostgreSQL non-time-series graph panel visualization

Tags: postgresql, grafana

I’m trying to get data structured like this:

---

[image: Query Results]

---

to look like this:

---

[image: Basic Bar Chart]

---

I am using the Graph Visualization with X-Axis mode set to Series.

My query is:

```
select
    t.name as Value,
    round(sum(i.points)/12, 1) as Metric
from
    event e,
    issue i,
    team t
where
    i.key = e.issue
    and t.id = i.assignee
    and e.type = 'Closed'
    and t.role = 'DEVELOPER'
    and e.date < (now() - interval '1 year')
group by Value
order by Metric
;
```

I’ve been reading Grafana Community topics and modifying my query for days. I can change the query/data structure to make this work. I would really appreciate some help.

- **Grafana Version**: v6.4.0 (c3b3ad4)
- **PostgreSQL Version**: PostgreSQL 10.9 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), 64-bit

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grafana is designated for time series. Yes, that is not your case, so you need to fake it - try to create fake "time" column with some value (current timestamp, constant, ...) (IMHO you have mixed metric/value):

```
SELECT
    1 AS "time",
    t.name AS metric,
    round(sum(i.points)/12, 1)
FROM
    event e,
    issue i,
    team t
WHERE
    i.key = e.issue
    AND t.id = i.assignee
    AND e.type = 'Closed'
    AND t.role = 'DEVELOPER'
    AND e.date < (now() - interval '1 year')
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Out of the scope this question: probably LEFT JOIN will be better to join tables

Comment: Thanks a bunch Jan! There's a lot of conflicting information on whether Grafana handles non-time-series data. I assumed that since it had a setting on the X-Axis for series, that it was updated to handle other data. Grafana is also missing a few event triggers when updating the chart. When I made the changes you suggested, it showed no data. When I turned the bars off and on again they suddenly showed up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using Bar Gauge visualization. In Display section choose Show: All values, Mode: Basic, Orientation: Vertical. In Field section choose Title: $__cell_0.
It will show the bars with the correct titles but you won't be able to display the texts with vertical orientation.